# What is the best way to find an http response that has a certain string of text in its response?

Tags: ajax, http, fiddler, wireshark

I'm debugging a web app with lots of AJAX on a windows machine.  I have Fiddler and Wireshark and I'm open to getting any other free software that can help.

I am looking for the http response (and its request) that contain a certain string in them.  What is the best way to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is utterly trivial in Fiddler. Cause the traffic to happen, then hit CTRL+F and type the string you're looking for.

If you want Fiddler to automatically mark any sessions that contain a given string, use the  [**utilFindInResponse** method](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Generate-Traffic/Tasks/SearchSequentialPages).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en/firefox/new/) with the [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/firebug/) addon!

Comment: Can you be more specific about how to find the AJAX with a string in it?

Comment: If the response is large, use the 'Copy response body' from the console tab. My Firebug is Dutch, but it does demonstrate what I mean: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11837707/stack_copy_firebug.png (Just paste it in notepad(++) and search :))